# telethon gives me error Button URL invalid

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I m trying to display specific Ad's but what is the error everything is ok or what am I wrong I am crazy with this

[image: img]

```
        if (luckyButtonNews != None):
        print("AAAAA",luckyButtonNews[0][0])
        print("BBBBBBB",luckyButtonNews[0][1])
        # keyboard = [[Button.url(luckyButtonNews[0][0],luckyButtonNews[0][1])]]
        keyboard = [[Button.url(str(luckyButtonNews[0][0]),str(luckyButtonNews[0][1]))]]
    else:
        keyboard = [[Button.url('Advertise your project here ', "https://t.me/contractchecker")]]

    chat = await BOT.get_entity(chatId)


    await BOT.send_file(chat, 'giphy.gif', caption= text,buttons=keyboard, parse_mode = 'HTML')
else:
    print("Waiting for the next update")
```

error:

```
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ButtonUrlInvalidError: Button URL invalid (caused by SendMediaRequest)
```

[image: print]

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot, one keyboard looks like `Button.url(url, text)` and the other like `Button.url(text, url)`. Make sure the text always comes first, and the URL always comes second.